# .NET documentation confusion around inheritance

Tags: c#, .net, class, inheritance, msdn

I am reading the .NET documentation, and encountered the [`IdentityReference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.identityreference?view=windowsdesktop-5.0) class, which states:

> Represents an identity and is the base class for the NTAccount and SecurityIdentifier classes. This class does not provide a public constructor, and therefore cannot be inherited.

My confusion is that it says it cannot be inherited, yet it also states it is the base class for the [`NTAccount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.ntaccount?view=windowsdesktop-5.0) and [`SecurityIdentifier`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.securityidentifier?view=windowsdesktop-5.0) classes. Based on my understanding, these classes are inheriting `IdentityReference`.

Is the documentation incorrect, or is my understanding incomplete? Should the documentation say 'This class does not provide a public constructor, and therefore cannot be **instantiated**'?

Comment: This means that class can't be inherited by application developers. It actually has an [internal ctor](https://source.dot.net/#System.Security.Principal.Windows/artifacts/obj/System.Security.Principal.Windows/Debug/net9.0/System.Security.Principal.Windows.notsupported.cs,32), so it can be inherited by the library authors.

Comment: It's likely that they have an internal constructor, meaning that the two derived types _can_ inherit from them because they are defined in the same assembly so have the appropriate access. However the documentation is correct that to external code/readers of the documentation, that _you_ can't inherit from it.

Comment: `internal` constructor and associated comment: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/1050695e16a29c48b6a08b599a060d3112b7a1e2/src/libraries/System.Security.Principal.Windows/src/System/Security/Principal/IdentityReference.cs#L8-L11

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation is correct. A child class must be able to call a base class constructor, whether the default parameterless constructor or another one. The `IdentityReference` class has no public or protected constructor though. If you try to inherit from it, you'll get a compilation error.

The class has [an *internal* constructor](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/principal/identityreference.cs,19), which allows classes in its own assembly to inherit from it

```
public abstract class IdentityReference
{
    internal IdentityReference()
    {
        // exists to prevent creation user-derived classes (for now)
    }
```

[NTAccount](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/principal/ntaccount.cs,20) is defined in the same assembly so it can inherit from `IdentityReference`:

```
public sealed class NTAccount : IdentityReference
{
...
```

The class is `sealed` though so other assemblies can't inherit from it either

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, what this means is that the constructor is *internal*, which means the class can be inherited only by classes in the same assembly.  So, when it says it "cannot be inherited" it really means it "cannot be inherited *by you*, the author of an external assembly".